# Get real-time comments from videos live Facebook-live-api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-live-api

I'm setting up an endpoint to receive real-time comments from the live streaming video, I follow the steps in this document smoothly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments/.

There was one person who commented directly on my live streaming video twice, and I also got those 2 comments, but that person's "id" in 2 comments is different. Can anybody explain me on this, and is there any way to fix it.

```
var source = new EventSource(
'https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/{live-video-id}/live_comments?access_token={access_token}&comment_rate=one_per_two_seconds&fields=from{name,id},message');

source.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(event.data);
};
```

> response 1:
> { "from": { name: "Joe Commenter", "id": 126577551217199 },"message":
> "I like it!" }
>
> response 2:
> { "from": { name: "Joe Commenter", "id": 23567175551752 },"message":
> "Great photo!" }

Comment: Are the IDs really that far apart - or do they differ somewhere in the last few digits only? (You seem to have copy&pasted the first one directly from the sample response in the documentation.)

Comment: Yes, I borrowed the response  form of the document to describe my problem, the commenter's IDs on the live video were completely heterogeneous.

Comment: may I know how did you manage to get the user id and name using the live comment api? what permission did you apply to review? because in my application when a user who does not have a role in FB APP comments on live feed I dont get the id and name. Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're two different accounts, probably a bot building a profile to be used for spam later.